# Proof of the Second Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Here's what I'm trying to prove:

Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $M$ and $N$ be linear subspaces of $V$. Then, it is the case that $M/(M \cap N)$ is isomorphic to $(M+N)/N$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Define the relation $Q: M/(M \cap N) \to (M+N)/N$ as follows:

$$\forall x \in M: Q(x+M \cap N) = x+N$$

This is totally defined so I will first show that it is well-defined. Suppose that $x+M \cap N = y + M \cap N$ for $x,y \in M$. Then, $x-y \in M \cap N$. So, $x-y \in M$ and $x-y \in N$. So:

$$x+N = y+N$$

$$\iff Q(x+M) = Q(y+M)$$

So, the function is well-defined.

We need to prove that this is linear and bijective. We will prove linearity first.

1. Proof of Additivity

Let $u,v \in M/(M \cap N)$. Then, $u = x + M \cap N$ and $v = y + M \cap N$ for some $x,y \in M$. So:

$$Q(u+v) = Q((x+y)+M \cap N) = (x+y) + N = (x+N) + (y+N) = Q(u) + Q(v)$$

That proves additivity.

2. Proof of Homogeneity

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ and $u \in M/(M \cap N)$. Then, $u = x+M \cap N$ for some $x \in M$. So:

$$Q(\alpha u) = Q(\alpha x + M \cap N) = \alpha x + N = \alpha (x+N) = \alpha Q(u)$$

That proves homogeneity. Hence, $Q$ is linear.

Now, we will need to prove bijectivity.

1. Proof of Injectivity

Let $u,v \in M/(M \cap N)$ such that:

$$Q(u) = Q(v)$$

Since $u = x + M \cap N$ and $v = y + M \cap N$ for some $x,y \in M$, we have:

$$x+N = y +N$$

$$\implies x-y \in N$$

So, $x-y \in M \cap N$ and that implies that:

$$x + M \cap N = y + M \cap N$$

Hence, $u = v$. That proves injectivity.

2. Proof of surjectivity

Let $x+N \in (M+N)/N$, where $x \in M+N$. Then:

$$\exists x' \in M: \exists n \in N: x = x'+n$$

Since $x-x' \in N$, it follows that:

$$x+N = x'+N$$

It is also the case that $Q(x'+M \cap N) = x'+N$. So, define $x'+M \cap N$ as the preimage of $x+N$ and we are done. This proves surjectivity.

Since $Q$ is linear and bijective, it follows that it is an isomorphism between $M/(M \cap N)$ and $(M+N)/N$. That proves the desired result.

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof looks absolutely correct. There is also another way to prove it, probably a bit shorter. You can define $\pi: M\to (M+N)/N$ by $\pi(x)=x+N$. This is clearly a linear map. It is also surjective, because for each $m\in M,n\in N$ we have $(m+n)+N=m+N=\pi(m)$, so the image of $\pi$ is all $(M+N)/N$.

Finally, we can compute the kernel of $\pi$. For $x\in M$ we have $\pi(x)=N$ if and only if $x+N=N$, if and only if $x\in N$, if and only if $x\in M\cap N$. Hence $Ker(\pi)=M\cap N$. Then it follows from the first isomorphism theorem that $M/(M\cap N)\cong (M+N)/N$.

Comment: Oh wow that is actually a really cool way to prove it. How did I not think of that? Urgh in any case, thank you so much!

Comment: @AbhijeetVats: Once you see this proof, you realise that a better way to think of the theorem is as follows: "Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $M$ and $N$ be vector subspaces of $V.$ Then $x\mapsto x+N$ defines a map $M\to M+N/N$ with kernel $M\cap N$." Then the first isomorphism theorem recovers the version you used to think about, and there is nothing "tricky" about the proof: you just verify exactly what the statement says. The third isomorphism theorem can be restated in a similar way.

Comment: ....There's a third isomorphism theorem? Also, yea, the proof is very, very simple. I'm in that weird position of having understood the definitions and having been able to construct the proof myself but not having any clue why it is even important in the first place so I'm just trying to grapple with that right now.

Comment: Third Isomorphism Theorem: Let $V$ be a vector space, let $M$ be a subspace of $V$, and let $N$ be a subspace of $M.$ Then $x+N\mapsto x+M$ defines a linear map $V/N\to V/M$ with kernel $M/N.$ So, by the First Isomorphism Theorem, $$\frac{V/N}{M/N}\cong \frac{V}{M}.$$ Slogan: "we can cancel the denominators". I'll leave you the proof as an exercise! :)

Comment: Ohhh I just saw this. Will make an attempt at it :D